# VPN disconeconnects when switching networks

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, firewall, vpn, privacy

**TL;DR** *If I am connected to one network and then connect to VPN it works fine, but if I then connect to a different network  then the VPN disconnects and tries to reconnect over the new network. I need it to stay "connected" while switching so I can maintain privacy and have mostly-unrestricted browsing using public wi-fi.*

Currently using Kubuntu 23.04 (laptop) and SteamOS (Steam Deck).

I frequently use my school's wifi, since it's free and faster than what I can afford at home. The kicker is that a lot of websites and downloads are blocked (things like .io, gaming, Steam, social media sites, etc.), also they monitor everything you do. To get around this I figured out that all I need to do is connect to a VPN, however, the school's network prevents you from connecting to one.

So I found a solution: first I connect to a VPN using a mobile hotspot then switch over to the school's wifi. Somehow the VPN remains on (this works with Android and Windows 10/11).

But with Linux this does not work because it's like the VPN totally turns off/disconnects between networks and tries to reconnect using the school's wifi, which doesn't allow you to use a VPN...so it doesn't connect...

I've tried using different VPNs (Nord, Proton, Open) and different setup options (Proton's app, Nord via CLI, Nord and Open via configuration files) and even different distros (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, and Mint) but haven't fixed the problem. Also, I do not have killswitch on.

Is there anything I can do to replicate the way VPN connections work on Windows and Android? That way it remains on when switching between internet connections.

Comment: so, in windows 10/11 you are connected to two wifis at once? the school and the mobile hotspot? Also, this wouldn't speed up the VPN connection, since the VPN is NOT connected through the "faster school wifi", since, you stated that the VPN is blocked through the "faster school wifi"

Comment: So I've been thinking about that. Because idk why it works on Windows and Android. But the best I can figure is that it either stays connected to the current network until the next network is fully connected to allow for uninterrupted internet service OR somehow those OSes allow you keep your IP address from the VPN while switching.
No it doesn't speed up the VPN, the VPN makes the schools wifi faster (I'm guessing because it runs through less security filters but idk I'm not an IT guru). It's especially noticeable on file downloads it seems like the speed is throttled based on size or source

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.